# IIS 7.5 FTP Service crashes after installation of Advanced Logging 1.0 Module

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, logging, iis-7.5, ftp

I've recently been tasked with setting up two new productions servers for an ASP.Net application. The servers sit behind a F5 Load Balancer, which in turn forwards the end users IP address forward via the standard X_Forwarded_For HTTP Header.

All of the reading that I have done suggests that I need to install the IIS Advanced Logging Module in order to take advantage of the X_Forwarded_For HTTP Header.

**Some quick background:**

Both of the web servers are Windows 2008 R2 Standard (x64), with IIS 7.5 installed and configured. 
The FTP Role has also been installed, configured and is operational.

**The Issue**

After installing the IIS Advanced Logging module via the Web Platform Installer, I noticed the following Error in the Event Viewer:

> The FTP Service encountered an error trying to read configuration data
>   from file
>   \?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config, line
>   number 374. The error message is: Unrecognized element
>   'advancedLogging'

Trying to connect over FTP to either of the web servers results in a 530.

I've spent 2 hours scouring Google trying to find a solution, short of uninstalling the Advanced Logging Module.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to turn off Advanced Logging on a site per site basis.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this issue while using Web Deploy 3.5.

Advanced logging was installed after the Web Deploy service, which caused the Web Management service to through the error "Unrecognized element 'advancedLogging' ".

Repairing the Web Deploy 3.5 installation resolved the issue.